# How to target -webkit-calendar-picker-indicator using react styled components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I need to create a custom date picker in react without using any libraries apart from styled components. Now, I want to edit a browser's regular date picker to fit my design. I have a problem targeting this in react styled components `-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator`. This is what I have done so far:

```
const DatePickerInput = styled.input` // input with type date
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 10%;
  margin-left: 12px;
  width: 0%;
  &::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;
```

If anyone knows how to target properly, It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to select the webkit using the `&` operator; all you have to do is to access it, like this:

```
  const DatePickerInput = styled.input` 
  ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;
```